# C# Exporting data of winforms application to excel

Tags: c#

I have no clue on how to export the data of my data from the windows forms application to a excel spreadsheet. After i click browse, selected the file I want and check the ACE. I want to export the data shown in the textbox to a Excel spreadsheet.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = filenameTextBox.Text;
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            aceInformationTextBox.Text = GetAccessControlInformation(filename);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Given file does not exist.", this.Text,
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

    }

    private string GetAccessControlInformation(string filename)
    {
        StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();
        info.AppendLine("ACE entries for the file \"" + filename + "\":");
        info.AppendLine();
        FileSecurity security = File.GetAccessControl(filename);
        AuthorizationRuleCollection acl = security.GetAccessRules(true, true,
            typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
        foreach (FileSystemAccessRule ace in acl)
        {
            string aceInfo = GetAceInformation(ace);
            info.AppendLine(aceInfo);
        }
        return info.ToString();
    }

    private string GetAceInformation(FileSystemAccessRule ace)
    {
        StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();
        string line = string.Format("Account: {0}", ace.IdentityReference.Value);
        info.AppendLine(line);
        line = string.Format("Type: {0}", ace.AccessControlType);
        info.AppendLine(line);
        line = string.Format("Rights: {0}", ace.FileSystemRights);
        info.AppendLine(line);
        line = string.Format("Inherited ACE: {0}", ace.IsInherited);
        info.AppendLine(line);
        return info.ToString();
    }

    private void browseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (browseFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filenameTextBox.Text = browseFileDialog.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void addSelfToAclButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = filenameTextBox.Text;
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            AddSelfToAcl(filename);
            aceInformationTextBox.Text = GetAccessControlInformation(filename);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Given file does not exist.", this.Text,
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }            
    }

    private static void AddSelfToAcl(string filename)
    {
        // create a rule for self
        WindowsIdentity self = System.Security.Principal.
            WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(
            self.Name, FileSystemRights.FullControl,
            AccessControlType.Allow);
        // add the rule to the file's existing ACL list
        FileSecurity security = File.GetAccessControl(filename);
        AuthorizationRuleCollection acl = security.GetAccessRules(true, true,
            typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
        security.AddAccessRule(rule);
        // persist changes and update view
        File.SetAccessControl(filename, security);
    }

    private void aceInformationTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void browseFileDialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should try a library such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com) or [some of the others](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2603625/1372125)

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you have 3 main options:

1. Export as a CSV file. This is the easiest option if your data doesn't contain any formatting. Despite the name 'comma separated values', most CSV files are actually tab-delimited. This makes them extremely easy to produce; you just need to output your values, placing a tab character (`\t`) between each cell, and a newline (`Environment.NewLine`) after each row.
2. Export to Excel using the OpenXML SDK. This is only suitable for the Excel 2007-2013 format, but this has been around for 7 years and is now widespread. Here's a good introductory resource: [Generating Excel 2010 Workbooks by using the Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180830%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
3. Export to Excel using Office Automation. You can't use this method if your application is running under ASP.NET or as a non-interactive Windows service, but it's fine for desktop and console applications. Another introductory example: [How to: Use COM Interop to Create an Excel Spreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I would personally advocate option 2 if you really need all the features of an Excel document (formatting, column widths, etc). If you just need the data, however, option 1 would be very quick to code.